# Method for click on UITableView when no cells are present so that keyboard will dismiss

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

On the screen a user can click a textfield to load a picker to select a Location. I then reload all elements in a tableview with custom cells based on this location. For some locations there may be nothing to load and so there are no cells.

When I have cells and the user clicks off the keyboard this part of code gets hit nicely:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.locationTextField resignFirstResponder];

    ...
}
```

I also have a piece of code that nicely handles not clicking anything

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

But when the tableview has no cells neither of these get fired when the user clicks the space of the tableview. Is there something else I can setup to detect touches on that area?

Comment: You could add a tap recognizer to the table view or the super view of the table view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using an `UITapGestureRecognizer` and add it to the table view.
Something like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableViewTap:)];
[self.myTableView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

and then:

```
-(void) tableViewTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer 
{
    CGPoint tapLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.myTableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];

    if (indexPath) //user tapped on a table cell
         recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    else //user tapped somewhere else on the table view
    {
        //your stuff here
    }
}
```